# Namespace Twig + composer

Tags: twig, namespace, composer, php

Добрый день, возникла следующая проблема. 
Установил через composer шабланизатор Twig. Проблемы в том, что он не видит namespace. Код приложения следующий.

```
include_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Компосер

include_once 'autoloadPSR4.php'; // Свои классы

$c_loader = new Autoload\Psr4AutoloadClass;
$c_loader->register();
$c_loader->addNamespace('app\Model', __DIR__ .'/models/');
$c_loader->addNamespace('app\Presenter', __DIR__ .'/presenter/');
$c_loader->addNamespace('app\ServiceClasses', __DIR__ .'/service_classes/');

use app\Presenter as Presenter;

$router = new Presenter\router($_GET);

$router->LoadController();
```

Каким образом я могу подключить Twig? Так

```
use Twig_\Twig as Twig;
$loader = new Twig\Twig_Loader_String();
$twig = new Twig\Twig_Environment($loader);
```

Comment: @barseon откуда вы вообще неймспейс выловили? Твиг лежит в корневом неймспейсе, по PSR-0. Зачем вы руками трогаете автозагрузчик композера?

Comment: то что выше это PSR4 автолоадер для моего фреймворка, для модели и контроллера. А автолоадер композера я не трогал, подключил как есть. Дело в том, что не могу подгружать твигавские классы по неймспейсу.

Comment: @barseon, у него нет неймспейса. Нету. Вообще. Это PSR-0, который базируется на стандарте раскидывания классов по папкам еще до тех пор, когда неймспейсы внедрили. `$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);`, без всяких use, автозагрузчик композера сам его найдет.

Comment: это получается, что мне в каждый класс контроллера нужно инклудить автолоадер. Либо сделать мейн класс контроллера, там засунуть его в метод или конструктор, и после унаследовать все контроллеры от главного и дергать метод рендера? Либо использовать traits. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @barseon, во фронт контроллер его засунуть надо. Фронт контроллер - это index.php.

Comment: выше приведенный код это и есть фронтконтроллер. Самой последней строчкой роутер выполняет подключение контроллера по адресу вроде site.ru/login/, где login это имя контроллера. А каким образом можно после подключения вызвать метод контроллера, например, в каждом контроллере будет метода result, который будет возвращать результат работы контроллера. Магическими методами вроде __invoke?

Comment: @barseon вы это имеете в виду?

    class Foo
    {
        public function bar($baz, $biz)
        {
            echo "$bar is not $biz";
            return false;
        }
    }

    $false = call_user_func_array(array(new Foo, 'bar'), array('baz', 'biz'));

Comment: Не совсем, вот мой фронтконтроллер с описанием, и почти в конце описана проблема. Возможно, так будет понятней. 

http://s7.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2015/03/294f96d4353deb8de78e34d8278fe576.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@barseon](/users/17085/barseon), по поводу вызова метода и был пример

```
class Foo
{
    public function bar($baz, $biz)
    {
        echo "$bar is not $biz";
        return false;
    }
}

$callable = array(new Foo, 'bar'); // первый элемент - объект, второй - имя метода. объект был создан на месте или был передан - нам без разницы. В данном случае тут был бы экземпляр контроллера и имя одного из его методов.
$arguments = array('baz', 'biz'); // список фргументов метода
$result = call_user_func_array($callable, $arguments); // неопсредственно вызов метода
```

По поводу "как передать в контроллер данные и шаблон".
Этим и занимается контроллер в MVC. Фронт-контроллер и приложение запускают контроллер, и на этом их ответственность (в таком примере) кончается. Все остальное ложится на плечи контроллера. Может, ему json надо отдавать - что, тоже через Twig?

Comment: Спасибо, получилось. 

    $load_controller = 'app\\'.'Presenter\\'.$controller;
    $current_class = new $load_controller;
    $result = call_user_func_array(array($current_class, 'render'), array());